# Bind longitude and latitude from Code behind on Google Maps API Version3 in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

Source Code aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ltlng = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default.aspx/getData",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {
                    var firstValue = parseFloat(item.FirstValue).toFixed(2);
                    var secondValue = parseFloat(item.SecondValue).toFixed(2);
                    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(firstValue, secondValue));
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        //alert("Test");
        markicons(ltlng);
    }

    var map; var infowindow;
    function InitializeMap() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.756, -73.986);
        var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    }

    function markicons(ltlng) {
        InitializeMap();
        map.setCenter(ltlng[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
            if (ltlng[i] != undefined) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: ltlng[i]
                });
                alert(ltlng[i]);
                (function (i, marker) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        if (!infowindow) {
                            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        }
                        infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(i, marker);

            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = loadData;
</script>
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">
</div>
```

Source Code for C#:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static object getData()
    {
        var obj = new { FirstValue = 17.22, SecondValue = 78.28 };
        var objList = (new[] { obj }).ToList();
        objList.Add(new { FirstValue = 13.5, SecondValue = 79.2 });
        objList.Add(new { FirstValue = 15.24, SecondValue = 77.16 });
        return objList;
    }
```

I am getting the result like this,
[image]

Tested Browser : Google Chrome. Please suggest me how can i resolve from this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your markicons(ltlng); method after you initialize your ajax request for the data.

You need to call this method AFTER you have got your data back.

Example:

```
success: function (data) {
            $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {
                var firstValue = parseFloat(item.FirstValue).toFixed(2);
                var secondValue = parseFloat(item.SecondValue).toFixed(2);
                ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(firstValue, secondValue));
            });

            // Call method here.
            markicons(ltlng);
        },
```